# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hola soy nuevo en React y estoy realizando un proyecto con hooks. El problema se presenta al tratar de recorrer un array que obtengo desde una API (pokeapi). Cuando obtengo la respuesta fetch la guardo a travez de useState. Ahora si quiero mostrar alguna propiedad del objeto no hay problema, pero si quiero recorrer una lista dentro del objeto me lanza el error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Pokemon() {

    let pokemonName = useParams().name

    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const jsonPokemon = async () => {
            const pokemonData = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}`)
            const pokemonJson = await pokemonData.json()
            setPokemon(pokemonJson)
        }
        jsonPokemon()
    }, [pokemonName])

    return (
        <Fragment>

        <h2>{pokemon.name}</h2>
        <h3>{pokemon.id}</h3>

        <ul>
            {
                pokemon.stats.map(value => (
                    <li>
                        {value.base_stat}
                    </li>
                ))
                
            }
        </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Un ejemplo del objeto que intento mostrar: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/bulbasaur
Especificamente la propiedad stats
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrias que validar que tu objeto contenga `stats`, y que `stats` tenga elementos.

```
{
    (pokemon.stats != null && pokemon.stats.length > 0)
    ?
    pokemon.stats.map(value => (
        <li key={value}>
            {value.base_stat}
        </li>
    ))
    :
    (<li>No existen datos</li>)
}
```

Agrego también `key={value}` en el `li`, ya que react lo requiere, caso contrario también te saldría un mensaje de advertencia.

Comment: Perfecto, fue un error de concepto, tenia entendido que por ejemplo con un AWAIT en un FETCH, se espera a recibir todos los datos antes de seguir, por lo tanto "no era necesario validar si los tenia", y lo podia recorrer sin problema. Veo que no es asi, podrias explicarme bien como funciona ¿O esto se comporta asi solo en el state en React?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es por el primer render y en la inicialización de la variable `pokemon`.

Primero que todo tienes que cambiar el valor por default que le estas pasando al `useState` de un array vacio a un objeto vacio, ya que la respuesta del endpoint es un objeto con la información del pokemon.

Para solucionar el error, tienes que validar que la propiedad `stats` exista en el objeto pokemon, ya que en el primer render, la variable `pokemon` es un objeto vacio y no tiene la propiedad `stats`.